# How to change Status Bar

Tags: java, android

I have this app, I have Header with background color grey, how can I set the Status Bar to the same color? I need to change the (blue-purple) color to the same as the header background Grey.

[image]

Comment: The blue part of your screenshot is called "status bar" :)

Comment: thanks, I will edit the Titte, and try to search about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this line in your code: `public abstract void setStatusBarColor (int color)` 
To "remove" the status bar write this: `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`